# How to delete specific node in omnixml delphi

Tags: delphi, omnixml

i've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594992/how-can-i-erase-a-child-node-row-with-omnixml)   but i don't know how to use that sample in my case. I have an xml file

```
 <Archive>                                  
  <Source>                               
     <Name>321</Name>                   
     <BatchID>123</BatchID>    
  </Source>                              
  <DataList>                             
     <Data>            
        <PN>AAAA</PN>
        <FN>1111</FN>
     </Data>
     <Data>            
        <PN>BBBB</PN>
        <FN>2222</FN>
     </Data>
  </DataList>                            
</Archive>
```

How can i delete the Node that has PN=BBBB?

---

I'm so sorry, i think i'm not clear in my question, my bad,
My Question is how to delete this section:

```
 <Data>            
    <PN>BBBB</PN>
    <FN>2222</FN>
 </Data>
```

not only this section

```
<PN>BBBB</PN>
```

---

The Answer:
Thanks to Runner, i modified a little bit of his code

```
  DeleteNode := XMLDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode('/Archive/DataList/Data[PN="BBBB"]');
  DeleteNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(DeleteNode);
```

Comment: Yes i'm aware of that question, you can see the link above in my first line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
  DeleteNode := OmniXML.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode('//[PN=''BBBB'']');
  DeleteNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild(DeleteNode);
```

You can search for it any other way. Note that the above example will only select first node occurence. But I recommend you look at [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/)

This is a set of interfaces that greatly simplify working with OmniXML. The above example would then be:

```
SimpleStorage.Remove('//[PN=''BBBB'']');
```

SimpleStorage also simplifies almost every other aspect of using the OmniXML and XML in general.

Comment: You should also disclose in the post that you are its author ;-)

Comment: Eh, it does not give any additional value to the answer ;)

Comment: You are right, Simple Storage (I keep promoting it) and your post are all OK but we must also consider this [section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) of the FAQ. Thank you again for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for support. The only reason why I mention SimpleStorage in my answers is because it can help a lot working with XML. And a lot of people do not know about it because it is not mentioned on the OmniXML site.

Comment: Primoz is your first promoter (Cromis.SS I mean) I knew: He never missed the opportunity to suggest people to use SS or GpFluentXML on top of OmniXML. Cromis.AnyValue and Cromis.Threading units are even in the OmniThreadLibrary ditribution under \bag of stuff\tmonitor-vs-commqueue. Thanks to him, I came across Cromis.SS.

Comment: I know Primoz, he is a great programmer and a big person :) Ah that other units are part of his queue test. We had a little competition.

Comment: Thanks Runner, i'll take a look at SimpleStorage